# SSH connections running in the background don't exit if multiple connections have been started by the same shell

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, stdin

Apparently, if the same shell launches multiple ssh connections to the same server, they won't return after executing the command they're given but will hang (`Stopped (tty input)`) for ever. To illustrate:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh localhost sleep 2
echo "$$ DONE!"
```

If I run the script above more than once in the background, it never exits:

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do foo.sh & done
[1] 28695
[2] 28696
[3] 28697
$                      ## Hit enter

[1]   Stopped                 foo.sh

[2]-  Stopped                 foo.sh

[3]+  Stopped                 foo.sh
$                      ## Hit enter again        
$ jobs -l
[1]  28695 Stopped (tty input)     foo.sh
[2]- 28696 Stopped (tty input)     foo.sh
[3]+ 28697 Stopped (tty input)     foo.sh
```

#### Details

- I found this because I was ssh'ing in a Perl script to run a command. The same behavior occurs when using Perl's `system()` call to launch `ssh`.
- The same issue occurs when using Perl modules instead of `system()`. I tried `Net::SSH::Perl`, `Net:SSH2` and `Net::OpenSSH`.
- If I run the multiple ssh commands from different shells (open multiple terminals) they work as expected.
- Nothing obviously useful in the ssh connection debugging info:

  ```
  OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
  debug1: Reading configuration data /home/terdon/.ssh/config
  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
  debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
  debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
  debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file /home/terdon/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/terdon/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/terdon/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/terdon/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/terdon/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/terdon/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/terdon/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/terdon/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
  debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.5
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
  debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'terdon'
  debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/terdon/.ssh/known_hosts"
  debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/terdon/.ssh/known_hosts:47
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
  debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
  debug3: send packet: type 20
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug3: receive packet: type 20
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
  debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
  debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
  debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
  debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
  debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
  debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
  debug2: languages ctos: 
  debug2: languages stoc: 
  debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
  debug2: reserved 0 
  debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
  debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
  debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
  debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
  debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
  debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
  debug2: languages ctos: 
  debug2: languages stoc: 
  debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
  debug2: reserved 0 
  debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
  debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
  debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug3: send packet: type 30
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
  debug3: receive packet: type 31
  debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:uxhkh+gGPiCJQPaP024WXHth382h3BTs7QdGMokB9VM
  debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/terdon/.ssh/known_hosts"
  debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/terdon/.ssh/known_hosts:47
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
  debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
  debug1: Found key in /home/terdon/.ssh/known_hosts:47
  debug3: send packet: type 21
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
  debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug3: receive packet: type 21
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
  debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
  debug2: key: /home/terdon/.ssh/id_rsa (0x555a5e4b5060)
  debug2: key: /home/terdon/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
  debug2: key: /home/terdon/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
  debug2: key: /home/terdon/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
  debug3: send packet: type 5
  debug3: receive packet: type 7
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
  debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
  debug3: receive packet: type 6
  debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug3: receive packet: type 51
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
  debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
  debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
  debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/terdon/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug3: send_pubkey_test
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
  debug3: receive packet: type 60
  debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
  debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:OGvtyUIFJw426w/FK/RvIhsykeP8kIEAtAeZwYBIzok
  debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:OGvtyUIFJw426w/FK/RvIhsykeP8kIEAtAeZwYBIzok
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug3: receive packet: type 52
  debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
  Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
  debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
  debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
  debug2: channel 0: send open
  debug3: send packet: type 90
  debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
  debug3: send packet: type 80
  debug1: Entering interactive session.
  debug1: pledge: network
  debug3: receive packet: type 80
  debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
  debug3: receive packet: type 91
  debug2: callback start
  debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
  debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IPV6_TCLASS 0x08
  debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
  debug1: Sending command: sleep 2
  debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
  debug3: send packet: type 98
  debug2: callback done
  debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
  debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
  debug3: receive packet: type 99
  debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
  debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
  ```
- This doesn't depend on my `~/.ssh/config` setup. Renaming the file doesn't change anything.
- This happens on multiple machines. I've tried 4 or 5 different machines running updated Ubuntu and Arch distros.
- The command (`sleep` in the dummy example but something a good deal more complex in real life) exits successfully and does what it's supposed to do. This doesn't depend on the command you're running, it's an ssh issue.
- This is the worst of them: *it isn't consistent*. Every now and then, one of the instances will exit and return control to the parent script. But not always, and there is no pattern I've been able to discern.
- Renaming `~/.bashrc` makes no difference. Also, I've run this on machines running Ubuntu (default login shell `dash`) and Arch (default login shell `bash`, called as `sh`).
- Interestingly, the issue only occurs if I hit any key (for example <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but any seems to work) after launching the loop but before the first script exits. If I leave the terminal alone, they finish as expected.

What's going on? Is this a bug in ssh? Is there an option I need to set? How can I launch multiple instances of a script that runs a command over ssh from the same shell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Foreground processes and terminal access control

To understand what is going on, you need to know a little about sharing terminals. What happens when two programs try to read from the same terminal at the same time? Each input byte goes randomly to one of the programs. (Not random as in the kernel uses an RNG to decide, just random as in unpredictable in practice.) The same thing happens when two programs read from a pipe, or any other file type which is a stream of bytes being moved from one place to another (socket, character device, …), rather than a byte array where any byte can be read multiple times (regular file, block device). For example, run a shell in a terminal, figure out the name of the terminal and run `cat`.

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/18
$ cat
```

Then from another terminal, run `cat /dev/pts/18`. Now type in the terminal, and watch as lines sometimes go to one of the `cat` processes and sometimes to the other. Lines are dispatched as a whole when the terminal is in cooked mode. If you put the terminal in raw mode then each byte would be dispatched independently.

That's messy. Surely there should be a mechanism to decide that one program gets the terminal, and the others don't. Well, there is! It triggers in typical cases, but not in the scenario I set up above. That scenario is unusual because `cat /dev/pts/18` wasn't started from `/dev/pts/18`. It's unusual to access a terminal from a program that wasn't started inside this terminal. In the usual case, you run a shell in a terminal, and you run programs from that shell. Then the rule is that the program in the foreground gets the terminal, and programs in the background don't. This is known as [terminal access control](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_04). The way it works is:

- Each process has a [controlling terminal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_03) (or doesn't have one, typically because it doesn't have any open file descriptor that's a terminal).
- When a process tries to access its controlling terminal, if the process is not in the foreground, then the kernel blocks it. (Conditions apply. Access to other terminals is not regulated.)
- The shell decides who is the foreground process. (Foreground process group, actually.) It calls the [`tcsetpgrp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetpgrp.html) to let the kernel know who should be in the foreground.

This works in typical cases. Run a program in a shell, and that program gets to be the foreground process. Run a program in the background (with `&`), and the program doesn't get to be in the foreground. When the shell is displaying a prompt, the shell puts itself in the foreground. When you resume a suspended job with `fg`, the job gets to be in the foreground. With `bg`, it doesn't.

If a background process tries to read from the terminal, the kernel sends it a SIGTTIN signal. The default action of the signal is to suspend the process (like SIGSTOP). The parent of the process can know about this by calling [`waitpid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) with the `WSTOPPED` flag; when a child process receives a signal that suspends it, the `waitpid` call in the parent returns and lets the parent know what the signal was. This is how the shell knows to print “Stopped (tty input)”. What it's telling you is that this job is suspended due to a SIGTTIN.

Since the process is suspended, nothing will happen to it until it's resumed or killed (with a signal that the process doesn't catch, because if the process has set a signal handler, it won't run since the process is suspended). You can resume the process by sending it a SIGCONT, but that won't achieve anything if the process is reading from the terminal, it'll receive another SIGTTIN immediately. If you resume the process with `fg`, it goes to the foreground and so the read succeeds.

Now you understand what happens when you run `cat` in the background:

```
$ cat &
$ 
[1] + Stopped (tty input)        cat
$
```

#### The case of SSH

Now let's do the same thing with SSH.

```
$ ssh localhost sleep 999999 &
$ 
$ 
$ 
[1] + Stopped (tty input)        ssh localhost sleep 999999
$
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> sometimes goes to the shell (which is in the foreground), and sometimes to the SSH process (at which point it gets stopped by SIGTTIN). Why? If `ssh` was reading from the terminal, it should receive SIGTTIN immediately, and if it wasn't then why does it receive SIGTTIN?

What's happening is that the SSH process calls the [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) system call to know when input is available on any of the files it's interested in (or if an output file is ready to receive more data). The input sources include at least the terminal and the network socket. Unlike `read`, `select` is not forbidden to background processes, and `ssh` doesn't receive a SIGTTIN when it calls `select`. The intent of `select` is to find out whether data is available, without disrupting anything. Ideally `select` would not change the system state at all, but in fact this isn't completely true. When `select` tells the SSH process that input is available on the terminal file descriptor, the kernel has to commit to sending input if the process calls `read` afterwards. (If it didn't, and the process called `read`, then there might be no input available at this point, so the return value from `select` would have been a lie.) So if the kernel decides to route some input to the SSH process, it decides by the time the `select` system call returns. Then SSH calls `read`, and at that point the kernel sees that a background process tried to read from the terminal and suspends it with SIGTTIN.

Note that you don't need to launch multiple connections to the same server. One is enough. Multiple connections merely increases the probability that the problem arises.

#### The solution: don't read from the terminal

If you need the SSH session to read from the terminal, run it in the foreground.

If you don't need the SSH session to read from the terminal, make sure that its input is not coming from the terminal. There are two ways to do this:

- You can redirect the input:

  ```
  ssh … </dev/null
  ```
- You can instruct SSH not to forward a terminal connection with `-n` or `-f`. (`-n` is equivalent to `</dev/null`; `-f` allows SSH itself to read from the terminal, e.g. to read a password, but the command itself won't have the terminal open.)

  ```
  ssh -n …
  ```

Note that the disconnection between the terminal and SSH has to happen on the client. The `sleep` process running on the server will never read from the terminal, but SSH has no way to know that. If the client receives input on standard input, it must forward it to the server, which will make the data available in a buffer in case the application ever decides to read it (and if the application calls `select`, it'll be informed that data is available).

Answer (score 4):

You may find help in the man page:

```
 -n      Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).  This must be used when ssh is run in the
         background.  A common trick is to use this to run X11 programs on a remote machine.  For example, ssh -n
         shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will start an emacs on shadows.cs.hut.fi, and the X11 connection will be automatically
         forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh program will be put in the background.  (This does not work if ssh
         needs to ask for a password or passphrase; see also the -f option.)
```

If that still doesn't help, I'd try `-T` (disable pseudo-tty allocation), just on a whim.

Comment: The `-n` resolves the issue. The `-T` is unrelated since if you run a command, it does not allocate remote TTY by default.

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently, if the same shell launches multiple ssh connections to the same server, they won't return after executing the command they're given but will hang (Stopped (tty input)) for ever.

This is common behavior of concurrent access to TTY. The whole process is already backgrounded and when it tries to write the output, it is not allowed to access TTY and receives a signal (`SIGTTOU`), which is not caught by `bash` process and therefore the default action is performed (`Stop`).

The `-n` option as explained in the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383502/22222) or redirection of the IO to some files will help you. Not sure if there is something more to describe, but if so, please clarify.

Comment: No, the output isn't the issue (although I didn't make that clear in the answer; sorry). The actual use case has both stdout and stderr redirected to files. Not, however, stdin which is most likely the problem as you and Ulrich pointed out.

Comment: The output of the whole script, or just some of the commands inside?

Comment: Both. The actual command run in the full script is something like `. file 
 2>&1; /bin/rm file >> $logFile 2>&1; cd dir 2>&1; command >> $logFile 2>&1`. So I don't redirect the stdout of the `source` or the `cd` but neither should have any, and anyway, I run this through a Perl module which is also redirecting the output of the entire command chain. *And* I also redirect the output of the parent script itself. So I really doubt it could be the output. I was pretty sure the problem was redirecting the input, but I wanted to be sure. I'll test more extensively tomorrow at work.