# ssh reads stdin without being asked to

Tags: ssh, pipe, openssh

These do not do the same:

```
$ seq 1000000 | (ssh localhost sleep 1; wc -l)
675173
$ seq 1000000 | (ssh localhost sleep 1 </dev/null; wc -l)
1000000
```

What is the rationale for `ssh` reading stdin?

Comment: So does `cat`. If fail to see the issue. There is an specific option provided to prevent it from doing that (`-n`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ssh always reads stdin unless you tell it not to with the `-n` option (or the `-f` option).

The reason is so that you can do things like

```
tar cf - somedir | ssh otherhost "tar xf -"
```

And it always does this because ssh has no way of knowing if your remote command accepts input or not.

Likely what is happening in your first command is that seq fills up the network and pipe buffers (seq -> ssh -> sleep), and since sleep isn't reading anything, it gets blocked waiting for more reads, and then sleep exits, causing those full buffers to be dumped, and then seq is unblocked, feeding the remainder to wc.

Note that you would get similar results with `seq 1000000 | ( cat | cat | sleep 1; wc -l)`

In your second command, it is still reading stdin, but you've externally assigned /dev/null to stdin.

Comment: If I got it right, you're basically saying that the local ssh client can't know if the remote commands (the ssh server and the `sleep` it runs) _need_ any data, so it has to make the data available in any case? Or in other words, there's no way for the remote to send the local side a request to make data available. I suppose that makes sense, since something like regular pipes also don't exactly work by passing requests for data either.

Comment: ... and you've actually got two regular pipes involved here.  ssh can't know the input won't be taken until it's too late.

Answer (score 5):

Unix input/output is based on unidirectional communication primitives: pushing data with `write`¹, pulling data with `read`¹, and querying the availability of data with `select`. It is not the same model as, for example, is common on the web, where the consumer of data sends a request “please give me some data” and the producer replies with the data, or the consumer sends a request “how much data can you give me?” and the producer replies with a size. A data consumer calls `read` to retrieve whatever data is available, and this doesn't necessarily need to involve the producer (e.g. pipes have a buffer and reading from the buffer doesn't have to involve the write end of the pipe). A data consumer can call `select` to know whether data is available, and this doesn't involve the producer at all.

The SSH server can know whether the application running on the server is actively trying to read from its standard input: the SSH server can call `select` to know whether writing data would block. But if the application tries reading intermittently, the SSH server might not call `select` at the right time, so it could miss that the application is trying to read data. And the SSH server has no way to know whether or when the application asks there's data available on its standard input by calling `select`. The only way the SSH server can provide data to the application when it wants is to provide data to the application when it's available.

This requires the client to transmit the data to the server. So the client reads its standard input and forwards data as soon as it's available.

Once the client has read some data from its standard input, it can't un-read it. If the server-side application doesn't end up consuming the data, it's lost.

As a consequence, when you're calling `ssh`, you need to decide on the client side whether you want standard input to be routed through the SSH connection or not. It's not something the server can tell you.

See also [SSH connections running in the background don't exit if multiple connections have been started by the same shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383501/ssh-connections-running-in-the-background-dont-exit-if-multiple-connections-hav/383570#383570) which explores a scenario that's similar, but more complex, involving terminals.

¹ <sub>and friends.</sub>

Comment: Re. calling `select()` to see if a write would block, wouldn't `select()` be capable of waiting for a change in the "writable" status of the fd, the same way it watches for other fds to become readable? All the SSH server would really need to know here is if the program _ever_ reads. But does `select()` actually tell if someone is actively calling `read()` on the fd? Or just that there's an fd open for reading, which might not mean the program is actually calling `read()` on it?

Comment: @ilkkachu The job of `select` is to tell whether read/write would block. Not whether there has been a time in the past when it didn't block. If the application tries reading from stdin for a while, then times out, and _then_ sshd calls `select`, sshd will not see that it can write without blocking.

Comment: no, of course not. But often the program (sshd here) using `select()` would spend most of its time blocking on the `select()` call, and so would be immediately notified when the fd becomes available.

Comment: Your second paragraph makes it seem like using `select` would work when the consumer does blocking `read`s, but not when it does non-blocking `read`s. However, even when the consumer only does blocking reads, `select` wouldn't work at the start, since writing would only block after the pipe buffer has filled. That means that in a typical pipe, before the producer has written anything, `select` would always return saying that writing wouldn't block, regardless of whether the consumer is trying to slurp, read intermittently, or not read at all.

Comment: Also, I agree with ilkkachu. If the pipe buffer weren't an issue (e.g. if it were possible to set its size to 0), then intermittent reads shouldn't be a problem, since `sshd` could via an alternate thread call `select` and stay blocked, while it starts the client-specified command. `select` would only return once the command tries to do any sort of read. Again, this is in the hypothetical scenario where the pipe buffer size could be set to 0. Right now, it must be at least equal to the page size.